# magento 1.9 switch theme on checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, rwd-theme

I am working on custom theme and i want to change to switch to RWD theme on checkout and cart page only , so when customer click on or come on checkout page i want to load RWD theme ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by overriding your controller class.

After overriding the controller file, suppose you want to set RWD theme for checkout cart action, then write the following code in the **`cartAction`** function in the **CartController.php**:

```
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')
    ->setPackageName('rwd') //Name of Package
    ->setTheme('default');// Name of theme
```

just before:

```
$this->loadLayout()
```

Similarly, you can make changes in OnepageController.php also.

Please let me know if anything is unclear in above explanation.